# An error to upload a ZIP file under apache ode: null model

Tags: apache, bpel, ode, bpmn

I have a workflow made in Intalio BPMN designer and a ZIP file with the contents of build directory (deploy.xml, wsdl, bpel), the problem is why this workflow doesn't deploy in Apache ODE.

The error displayed in Apache ODE is: Invocation of operation deploy failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null model.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? What happens if you copy the extracted zip in a separate folder to ode/WEB-INF/processes/?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but here's an answer:

This rather unhelpful error message is the result of ODE processing an import which has no schema location attribute, such as:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="something" >
        <xsd:import namespace="somethingElse" />
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Add the missing `schemaLocation` attribute:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="something" >
        <xsd:import namespace="somethingElse" schemaLocation="somethingElse.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

**Also check your `<wsdl:import/>` and `<bpel:import/>` tags for missing `location` attributes.**